# Connecting both my mixers and my audio interface to my studio monitors

Tags: mixer, audio-interfaces, studio-monitors

My studio monitors: alesis elevate 5 mkii. As you can see by their specs, they have 2x rca and 2x 1/4 line inputs. But both pairs are parte of same input module, so i guess it would be harmful (correct me if im wrong) to have two sources connected at the same time and both of them powered on. But what if i have an audio interface powered off connected to rca ins and my mixer to the 1/4s powered on or vice versa? Basically i would love to be able to have them both hooked up to the monitors to able to use one if them without switching cables. Any hint?

Comment: ugh this is a bad idea

Comment: @TylerStone even if i carefully have only one of the devices powered on? Never the two

Comment: despite being powered off, it's output stage could present itself to the other device (the one that's on) as a low impedance load, impairing signal integrity.

Comment: can you just connect everything to the mixer and go from there to the monitors?

Comment: Thats precisely what i did. Audio interface to 2-track in

Answer (score 1):

You should consider a "Studio Monitor Controller" with the appropriate number of input (stereo-)channels, and appropriate amount of output (stereo-)channels for your specific requirements.

> Connecting both my mixers and my audio interface to my studio monitors

This title of your question indicates 3 input (stereo-)channel/sources

> two sources connected at the same time

This statement in the text of your question indicates 2 input (stereo-)channel/sources.

There are various models available, for all kinds of budgets:

- Example of a 4 input device for an affordable budget: [Behringer Control2USB](https://www.thomann.de/ie/behringer_control2usb.htm)
- Example of an 8 input device for a larger budget: [Antelope Satori](https://www.thomann.de/ie/antelope_satori.htm)

The usage of a "Studio Monitor Controller" would be the preferred way of connection multiple sources to Studio Monitor speakers.

*Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with either websites, nor products mentioned in links above. Nor do I claim, nor warrant, any functionality of either device.*